# easy way extract elements in matrix

Tags: matlab

Suppose a=

```
3 2 5
0 1 6
```

and table =

```
1 2 1
1 2 2
```

I want to extract particular elements in each column of a, row indexed by table. The result should be

```
3 1 5
3 1 6
```

Iterating through each column will take too long. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: please post executable code to make sure what you mean by "table". Also use different numbers for `a` than just 0 and 1, even if it's your case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sub2ind to do that, like this:

```
a(sub2ind(size(a), table, columns))
```

Where `columns` is a matrix like `table`, but containing the column indexes, like this:

columns =

```
 1 2 3
 1 2 3
```

There are many ways you could create that matrix. Here are some ways:

```
columns = cumsum(ones(size(a)), 2)
columns = repmat(1:size(a,2), size(a, 1), 1)
columns = ones(size(a,1),1) * (1:size(a,2))
```

Or you could create that matrix directly in the function call, and do it all in one line:

```
a(sub2ind(size(a), table, cumsum(ones(size(a)), 2)))

ans =

     3     1     5
     3     1     6
```

Comment: Nice answer! One more thing, I have changed the case to be clearer and you may edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein as [Rafael Monteiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23171532/2586922):

```
result = a(bsxfun(@plus, table, 0:size(a,1):numel(a)-1));
```

Since time is of concern, test to see which approach is fastest in your specific case.

Comment: `bsxfun`! That name is enough ;)